# regionIsoCode is always (not set)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm extracting data from Google Analytics via the Reporting API. We are seeing many rows where the Region is showing a value, e.g. "Texas", but the regionIsoCode is "(not set)". In fact, all tests so far result in every value of regionIsoCode as "(not set)". I confirmed the data is the same on our google.com/analytics dashboard.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this unusual behavior?

Note: This is a cross post from productforums.google.com.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you get any resolution perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Honestly I can't even find my original post on the Google forums to see if anyone may have responded there. We're doing the best we can without it by using our own kind of translation table.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old thread, but this bubbles up to the top and I just ran into this myself.

Here is my use case, when I ran the query with the following setup, if end is any time in the future, I always got '(not set)'. Once I made sure 'end' is set to 'yesterday' or some date earlier than yesterday, it worked.

```
query({
   'ids': ids,
   'dimensions': 'ga:city,ga:region,ga:regionIsoCode',
   'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:sessionsPerUser,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:users,ga:newUsers,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:bounceRate',
   'sort': '-ga:sessions',
   'max-results': 20,
   'start-date': start,
   'end-date': end <--- make sure this is 'yesterday' or earlier
 })
```

Comment: Sweet! Glad this works. Unfortunately, I work for a different company now, so I can't even go back to see if that was the issue.